# How can I return view inside actual view (in same page)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I'm learning Laravel and I have a view with a contact list and inside of this table I have a button to display more details about the clicked item. I want to return a view inside the actual view, I don't want to go to another page.

Someone can explain me how can I do that and show me examples of that if it is possible?

I already try do that using ajax but I don't now how can I return a view without go to other page.

```
$("#detailsItemSize").click(function() 
{
    var itemId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    alert("details");
    alert(url);
    $.ajax
    ({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url + "/" + itemId,
        data: {'itemId': itemId, _token: token }    
    });
    .done(function (msg) 
    {
        console.log(msg['message']); 
    });
});
```

Best regards

Comment: The controller code which handles `url + "/" + itemId` can create and `render` a view which jQuery can then use. Also, I find it very hard to believe you're using 3 different versions of Laravel and your code is purely JavaScript/jQuery which you have not tagged at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic premise is to have a route that renders your partial view:

```
Route::get('item/{item}', function($itemId){
    $someitem = Item::findOrFail($itemId);
    return view('partial', compact('someitem'));
});

//partial.blade.php

<h1>Items id is {{$someitem->id}}</h1>

//main view

<div id="details></div>

//js

$.get('/item/27', function(response){
    $('#details').html(response);
});
```

the `#details` div in the page will contain `<h1>the items id is 27</h1>` when the ajax call returns